# Define a macro for a vector to display differently in inline/display math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath, vector, arguments

I'd like to define a command that defines a vector based on whether it's in display or inline math mode. I've tried this so far, but it hasn't worked:

```latex
\newcommand{\ve}[1]{\ensuremath{%
    \mathchoice{%
        \begin{pmatrix}%
            \StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{\\}%
        \end{pmatrix}%
    }{%
        \left(\begin{smallmatrix}%
            \StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{\\}%
        \end{smallmatrix}\right)%
    }{#1}{#1}%
}}
```

I'd like to get `$$\ve{1,2,x}$$` to expand to

```latex
\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\2\\x
\end{pmatrix}
```

and `$\ve{1,2,x}$` to expand to

```latex
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1\\2\\x
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
```

Comment: Are you willing and able to entertain a LuaLaTeX-based solution, or does it have to work with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Please also indicate how or where `\StrSubstitute` is defined.

Comment: @Mico I'd like to stick to PDFLaTeX. `\StrSubstitute` is defined in the `xstrings` package (or something like that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Distinguishing inline and display math is different from distinguishing `\displaystyle` from `\textstyle` and can be tricky, since the `align`-like environments of `amsmath` use internally `$\displaystyle...$`. Your definition with `\ensuremath` will furthermore always use `\textstyle` if you call the macro outside of math mode.
In my (of course questionable) opinion `\ensuremath` shouldn't be used unless the life of sweet kittens and fluffy bunnies depends on it; and also in that case it shouldn't be used lightly.

Luckily, `amsmath` provides a boolean `\if@display`, so we can (ab)use it. I'd load `mathtools`, an extension to `amsmath`, which among other things defines already a `psmallmatrix` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\ve}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \if@display
      \def\@tempa{{pmatrix}}
   \else
      \def\@tempa{{psmallmatrix}}
   \fi
   \expandafter\begin\@tempa
   \@ve#1,\@@nil,
   \expandafter\end\@tempa
   \endgroup
}
   
\def\@ve#1,{\ifx\@@nil#1\else#1\\\expandafter\@ve\fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hsize=4cm % for the snapshot

\[
\ve{a}\ve{a,b}\ve{a,b,c}
\]

\begin{align*}
\ve{a}\ve{a,b}\ve{a,b,c}
\end{align*}

$\ve{a}\ve{a,b}\ve{a,b,c}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** A version which [like egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579461/82917) uses `\mathchoice`. I've added for completeness also a row vector. This required some more trickery, becase there is no harm in adding `\\` at the end of a column vector (like my first coded did) but it goes wrong when you add a `&` at the end of a row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\cvector}[1]{\cr@vector{\\}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\rvector}[1]{\cr@vector{&}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\cr@vector}[2]{%
   \mathchoice{\cr@@vector{#1}{#2}{}}%
              {\cr@@vector{#1}{#2}{small}}%
              {\cr@@vector{#1}{#2}{small}}%
              {\cr@@vector{#1}{#2}{small}}%
}

\newcommand*{\cr@@vector}[3]{%
   \def\@tempa{\gdef\@tempa{#1}}% first time does nothing, afterwards it's \\ or &
   \def\@tempb##1,{\ifx\@@nil##1\else\@tempa##1\expandafter\@tempb\fi}%
   \begin{p#3matrix}
   \@tempb#2,\@@nil,
   \end{p#3matrix}
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\hsize=5cm % for smaller snapshot

Display
\begin{align*}
\rvector{a,b,c} \cvector{a,b,c}
= \frac{\rvector{x,y} \cvector{u,v}}{\rvector{1,2,3}\cvector{4,5,6}}
\end{align*}
and inline $\rvector{a,b,c}$, $\cvector{a,b,c,d,e}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

One could use `\mathchoice` directly in the definition of `\cvector` and `\rvector` and spare one intermediate macro but I find the code would be less readable.

Comment: Thanks @campa! This works perfectly, is extremely readable, and doesn't involve importing extra packages. The `\psmallmatrix` is genius as well!

Comment: @Raymo111 Readability might be one thing, but as far as egreg's answer is concerned consider that (1) `xparse` is a rather standard package and even for an older distribution where it's not part of the format you might already have it (maybe you don't load it directly but there are many common packages which do) and (2) my solution will give you larger matrices also e.g. in fractions, while egreg's will give you smaller matrices. Not that anybody in their sane mind would type something like that, but keep the difference in mind.

Comment: I get that `xparse` is standard, but if I'm sharing `\ve` with friends I don't really want to make them import xparse if they're not on the latest Tex distribution. What do you mean by larger/smaller matrices?

Comment: @Raymo111 Try using the `\ve` macro in an argument of `\frac`. My version will stay large; egreg's will become smaller (which is the sensible behaviour).

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: For the first version for some reason this doesn't work: `\ve{((a)),b}`. This does though: `\ve{\big((a)\big),b}`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Raymo111 LOL, yes, I know what is wrong `:-D` In the definition of `\@ve` there is `\ifx#1\relax`, and in this case this becomes `\ifx((a))\relax` so the two `(` are compared and they are of course equal... I can't test now but quick fix: use `\ifx\relax#1` instead. I'll see tomorrow if there are more pitfalls.

Comment: Ahh ok. I'm not in any particular rush, but the code is on GitHub and people were asking me when I'd add to it LOL. https://github.com/Raymo111/latex-templates/blob/master/Math%20Macros.tex

Comment: Also Massive Kudos to you and @egreg you LaTeX geniuses. This stuff is like Cuneiform to me :/

Comment: Can confirm that swapping `\relax` and `#1` makes it work. Also you couldn't put 11 into a vector with the original version, which is hilarious. Glad it works now though :)

Comment: @Raymo111 See edit. Should be safer now.

Comment: Can confirm it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The idea is good. Not so `\ensuremath`, of course.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn is just to get a smaller picture
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ve}{m}
 {
  \mathchoice
    {\raymo_ve_display:n {#1}}
    {\raymo_ve_inline:n {#1}}
    {\raymo_ve_inline:n {#1}}
    {\raymo_ve_inline:n {#1}}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__raymo_ve_make:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__raymo_ve_body_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__raymo_ve_body_seq { \\ }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \raymo_ve_display:n
 {
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \__raymo_ve_make:n { #1 }
  \end{pmatrix}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \raymo_ve_inline:n
 {
  \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
  \__raymo_ve_make:n { #1 }
  \end{smallmatrix}\right)
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is inline $\ve{1,2,x}$ and there is also a display
\[
\ve{1,2,x}
\]

\end{document}
```

If you're not running the latest LaTeX kernel (2020-10-01), you need `\usepackage{xparse}`.

I find `expl3` much better than `xstrings`.

[image]

“Optimized” code for also supporting row vectors:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn is just to get a smaller picture
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\gve}{mm}
 {% #1 = c or r
  \mathchoice
    {\raymo_ve_build:nnn {#1}{#2}{}}
    {\raymo_ve_build:nnn {#1}{#2}{small}}
    {\raymo_ve_build:nnn {#1}{#2}{small}}
    {\raymo_ve_build:nnn {#1}{#2}{small}}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\ve}{m}{\gve{c}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rve}{m}{\gve{r}{#1}}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__raymo_ve_make:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__raymo_ve_body_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__raymo_ve_body_seq { \str_case:nn {#1}{{c}{\\}{r}{&}} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \raymo_ve_build:nnn
 {
  \begin{p#3matrix}
  \__raymo_ve_make:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \end{p#3matrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is inline $\ve{1,2,x}\rve{1,2,x}$ and there is also a display
\[
\ve{1,2,x}\rve{1,2,x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a working answer! Upvoted, though I must accept @campa's answer as it doesn't involve using `xparse` and is overall shorter and easier to read.